# sscanf reading a string within a string

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a small problem that I can't seem to fix. Say I have a string,

`buffer = "1 1 X ./simple E"`

And I want to extract the 2 ints, 2 chars and the filename,

`sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c, &a, &b, &c, d, &e);`

`printf("%d %d %c %s %c", a, b, c, d, e);`

I don't get back quite what I expect. I get "11 1 X (null)". Any help appreciated.

Comment: how are a b c d e declared?

Comment: a, b are int, c, e are char, and d is char*.

Comment: Make d like this "char d[100];"

Comment: Thanks everyone. Will add full code in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `char *d`, which will fail because it has no valid place to point. Use an array that has enough space will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char c, e;
    char d[20];
    char buffer[] = "1 1 X ./simple E";
    sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c", &a, &b, &c, d, &e);
    printf("%d %d %c %s %c", a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

OUtput: `1 1 X ./simple E`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    char buffer[] = "1 1 X ./simple E", c, d[10], e;
    int a, b;

    //sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %*[./]%s %c", &a, &b, &c, d, &e); //To ignore "./"
    sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c", &a, &b, &c, d, &e); //Don't ignore "./"
    printf("%d %d %c %s %c\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 X ./simple E
```

Answer (score 0):

c and e can be int's or chars. Note the overflow issues with d[100].

```
int a, b, c, e;
char d[100];
sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c, &a, &b, &c, d, &e);

printf("%d %d %c %s %c", a, b, c, d, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

No blank space delimiter need in the sscanf function argument.

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%c%s%c", &a, &b, &c, d, &e);
```

`%d` is blank separated when when reading buffer, and there should not be a space between `%c` and `%s`, cause it swallow the space, leaving the buffer with no separator between char and string.